# How to turn bluetooth on in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth

In the Task bar, it shows that Bluetooth is ON . But when I checked Bluetooth settings, it shows bluetooth is disabled and also I am not able to switch OFF to ON state. Is there any way to turn bluetooth on. Guys please help me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check that your bluetooth was unlocked on rfkill.

```
sudo rfkill list
```

In case your bluetooth is Soft blocked you can unblock it by running the below command,

```
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

In case your bluetooth is Hard blocked,then try to find a hardware switch on your laptop to unblock it.

Comment: This was the output I got.
hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no